# .reloadData() fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am following this tutorial: http://jamesonquave.com/blog/developing-ios-apps-using-swift-part-3-best-practices/#comment-12898

I am getting an error `“fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value”.`

```
func didRecieveAPIResults(results: NSDictionary) {
  var resultsArr: NSArray = results["results"] as NSArray
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
  self.tableData = resultsArr
  self.appsTableView!.reloadData() // Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
  })
}
```

Here is the code from my github: https://github.com/a9austin/JamesHelloWorldTutorial/tree/master/Part1HelloWorld

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for the error is your project does not have an appsTableView in the storyboard. As a result it is not connected to the IBOutlet as shown in the tutorial in Part 2:

http://jamesonquave.com/tutImg/ConnectTableView.png

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have connected the IBOutlet, I have completed part 2 and ran successfully. If it was not connected I don't think part 2 would have ran. However I did rename the ViewController to ResultSearchViewController. I renamed everything mentioned in the tutorial.

Comment: I downloaded your github project and there  was no TableViewController in the storyboard.

Comment: ^ that was the issue... haha. I have no idea how I deleted it. Thanks!